# How to do auto-complete in ionic 2 (search-bar)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to do an auto complete in my search bar what i have done so far is.

I have an array with some strings. and then i am trying to list in my items it i am able to search the particualr item.

But my requirement is not to display the items in a list. I have to make on clicking the search bar all the strings in array should come and the i have to make a search.

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>search</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
  <ion-toolbar primary >
    <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)" autocorrect="off"></ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{ item }}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>  

</ion-content>
```

Code for search.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

/*
  Generated class for the SearchPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/search/search.html',
})
export class SearchPage {
private searchQuery: string = '';
  private items: string[];

  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.initializeItems();
  }

  initializeItems() {
    this.items = [
      'Amsterdam',
      'Bogota',
    ]
  }

  getItems(ev: any) {
    // Reset items back to all of the items
    this.initializeItems();

    // set val to the value of the searchbar
    let val = ev.target.value;

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
        return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }
}
```

**Question :**

> How to get the value of an array through auto complete in ionic 2.

Comment: Could you please add the code of your view as well?

Comment: I have add my code both HTML and .ts file please take a look at it. I am new to this

Comment: I see in Ionic docs that they have autocomplete property for searchbar, have you tried this?  
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/

Comment: i have no idea can you please help me how to use autocomplete property

Comment: What do you mean by 'I have to make on clicking the search bar all the strings in array should come and the i have to make a search'?

Comment: when i click the searchbar i want to get my items [this.items list] in my search.html page.

Comment: when i click the searchbar i want to get my items [this.items list] in my search.html page

Comment: But the search bar is an input, do you mean clicking a button inside that search bar?

Comment: i need somthing like this in ionic2 http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/pCwyx

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, my search bar behaves in the same way as the codepen provided above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to achieve that, you just need to add a small thing to your code. Please take a look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/o6YGCA?p=preview).

Like you can see there, with the `showList` variable we can show the results only after the user has searched something.

```
  <ion-list *ngIf="showList">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{ item }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

We first set that variable to `false` in the `constructor` and then we set it to `true` inside the `getItems(...)` method.

Comment: i did same thing but i got error at this.items array

Comment: But the plunker is working properly. Could you please take a look carefully to see what's the difference between that plunker and your code?

Comment: @sebaferreras you are giving `showlist= true` so when will the list become false for example if the user cancelled all the inuput sting in search bar so I think the list will still apear

Comment: @MohanGopi Yeap, that's true. But that's also happening in the codepen provided AFAIK. We could do `showlist=false` in that case to hide the list but I tried to create the same behavior in that plunker.

Comment: @sebaferreras i tried the below code to make it false but did not work can you update your plunknr `if (ev.target.value == null){
      this.showList = false;
    }else{
      this.showList = true;
    }` inside the getItems(ev) function

Comment: @sebaferreras I tried your code but i am facing a problem with cancel button i am getting the button in prefix and the icon looks like backbutton but in your plunknr you are getting icon as 'x' i dont know why any idea

Comment: @MohanGopi to avoid showing the cancel button at the beginning, add `[showCancelButton]="false"`. And I've created this [new plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DAoKJR?p=preview) where I hide the results when the content of the search bar is empty. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @sebaferreras plunker link is broken..can you update it, please?

Comment: @varunaaruru the plunker of the answer has been updated. Please let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: thanks :) its working and helped me in my app :) @sebaferreras

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)