# Ionic 2 input text autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, ionic2

I am using ionic 2.

I have an array value.

I need input text with autocomplete.

Answer (score 6):

1. First create a modal
2. keep search in that modal
3. After selecting the list in that modal.
4. close the modal and bind value to input.

example

in html

```
<ion-item inset>
              <ion-label floating i18n>Gotram*</ion-label>
              <ion-input type="text" (focus)="selectGotram()" readonly [(ngModel)]="user.gotram" name="gotram" #gotram="ngModel" required></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
```

in component

```
selectGotram() {
  let data = { "title": "Gotram", "form": "show_autocomplete", "data": gotrams }
        let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(HelperComponent, data);
        modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
          if (data) {
            this.user.gotram = data;
          }
        });
        modal.present();
}
```

in helper component modal html

```
 <ion-searchbar showCancelButton="true" (ionInput)="getItems($event)" (ionCancel)="clearItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="selected_item">
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of data" (click)="selectedItem(item)">
          <ion-label>{{item}}</ion-label>
          <ion-radio [value]="item"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item *ngIf="data?.length ==0">
          <h2>no matched items</h2>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

in helper component modal

```
this.data = this.params.get('data');
 this.auto_complete = this.data;

  getItems(ev) {
    // set val to the value of the ev target
    var val = ev.target.value;
      console.log(val);
    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.data = this.auto_complete.filter((item) => {
        return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
     console.log(this.data);
  }
  clearItems(ev) {
    // set val to the value of the ev target
    var val = ev.target.value;
    console.log(val);
    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.data = this.auto_complete.filter((item) => {
        return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }
  selectedItem(item) {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(item);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Autocomplete is not support by `input` component.

but instead you can use:

1. `select` component. check this [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#select).
2. `Searchbar` component. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093052/how-to-do-auto-complete-in-ionic-2-search-bar)

also check this [ionic2-autocomplete](https://github.com/kadoshms/ionic2-autocomplete)

Answer (score 0):

You could try an external library such as [ionic4-auto-complete](https://GitHub.com/jrquick17/ionic4-auto-complete) which supports Ionic 2+ and Angular 2+.